# angular2 bundle node_modules only and not application code

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, webpack-2

Angular v.4 and webpack

i am looking for answer of very simple question.

How can i bundle node_module folder as vendor.js but not your application code. on page load seems like there are more then 300 requests from angular code to load internal files.

if i am able to merge all node_modules libraries i will save lot of browser requests.

I followed this [example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) was able to get it run but it bundles libraries and your application code as well. i was able to successfully generate the vendor.js only but i am not sure after i add vendor.js in `index.html` how my application code will recognize @angular lib references. currently it is being resolved using `systemjs.config.js` some thing like this

```
@angular/code : 'npm:@angular/code/bundle/core.umd.js' 
..
..
```

and exactly thats what happen as i thought application crashed it can't find references to @angular from my application code.

is it possible to just bundle `node_module` folder into `vendor.js` and still able to use in my application code without bundling app code ?

adding webpack config

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod.js');
```

**`webpack.common.js`**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
          } , 'angular2-template-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false // workaround for ng2
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

Comment: pretty sure `ng build` (or something of the sort - can't remember exactly) would do it for you and store it in the dist folder. But that's using angular-cli tho

Comment: What does your webpack config look like?

Comment: What do you mean by '300 requests'? There won't be 300 requests with Webpack, only 1 or several. What exactly is the reason why you want vendor.js? This only makes sense if you have several apps per site that share same third-party modules.

Comment: @estus i meant without webpack its lot of resource requets that i wana avoid using bundling node_modules into vendor.js

Comment: @estus so i have only project at this point using angular, so you think i don't need to bundle node_module and create vendor.js ?

Comment: @Sasang i have updated a question with  webpack.config.js configuration

Comment: It just makes no sense with a single app entry point. I'm not sure what exactly was the problem with vendor.js, but you can use it only within another Webpack entry (e.g. `app`). You can't use it standalone, with System.import or whatever.

Comment: So are you not getting main.js, vendor,js and some chunk files in yoour dist folder?